# Get lat/lng when clicking on MapQuest Map

Tags: javascript, php, mapquest

If someone can help me. How can I retrieve `Longitude` and `Latitude` when I click on MapQuest Map? Can this be done with EventManager `MQA.EventManager.addListener(map, 'click', eventRaised);` if so then how? I'm using Javascript Maps API v7.0

Answer (score 1):

Just came across a blog that answered my question. Here is the code if someone else ever needs help:

```
MQA.EventManager.addListener(map, 'click', eventRaised);

function eventRaised(event)
{
    var lat = event.ll.getLatitude();
    var lng = event.ll.getLongitude();
    alert(lat+' '+lng);
}
```